# The method is undefined for the type

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to implement a card game called 500.

Right here, I'm trying to index every type of bid possible into a simple index number.
I've already created the enums for the suits in another class.
The problem I have right now is that I keep on getting an error

"The method Bid(int, Card.Suit) is undefined for the type Bid".

I dont understand why this is happening.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public Bid(int pTricks, Suit pSuit)
{
    assert pTricks >= 6;
    assert pTricks <= 10;
    this.trickCount = pTricks;
    this.trumpSuit = pSuit;
}


public Bid(int pIndex)
{

    switch (pIndex) {
    case 0: Bid(6, Suit.SPADES);
    case 1: Bid(6, Suit.CLUBS);
    case 2: Bid(6, Suit.DIAMONDS);
    case 3: Bid(6, Suit.HEARTS);
    case 4: Bid(6, null);
    case 5: Bid(7, Suit.SPADES);
    case 6: Bid(7, Suit.CLUBS);
    case 7: Bid(7, Suit.DIAMONDS);
    case 8: Bid(7, Suit.HEARTS);
    case 9: Bid(7, null);
    case 10: Bid(8, Suit.SPADES);
    case 11: Bid(8, Suit.CLUBS);
    case 12: Bid(8, Suit.DIAMONDS);
    case 13: Bid(8, Suit.HEARTS);
    case 14: Bid(8, null);
    case 15: Bid(9, Suit.SPADES);
    case 16: Bid(9, Suit.CLUBS);
    case 17: Bid(9, Suit.DIAMONDS);
    case 18: Bid(9, Suit.HEARTS);
    case 19: Bid(9, null);
    case 20: Bid(10, Suit.SPADES);
    case 21: Bid(10, Suit.CLUBS);
    case 22: Bid(10, Suit.DIAMONDS);
    case 23: Bid(10, Suit.HEARTS);
    case 24: Bid(10, null);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `this` keyword to invoke the other constructor.

e.g.

```
case 24: this(10, Suit.HEARTS); break;
```

Also, make sure to have `break;` at the end of each case.

Edit: This doesn't work as indicated in comments below. Move this logic into a private method that you call from the constructors, or use a static factory method to replace the second constructor.

Comment: An explicit constructor invocation needs to be the first statement, no?

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to bring this up. With this, I would get a "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor" error.

Comment: Ah, right you are. Create a private "initialize" or similar method and call that in both constructors, then.

Answer (score 2):

Use a static initializer:

```
public static Bid create(int pIndex) {
    switch (pIndex) {
    case 0: return Bid(6, Suit.SPADES);
    case 1: return Bid(6, Suit.CLUBS);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. "The method Bid(int, Card.Suit) is undefined for the type Bid"
   That's right! There is no method with that signature - Bid(int, Card.Suit) is a **constructor**. (I can tell, because of the missing return type or keyword *void* between the access modifier and the name)
2. To invoke a constructor from another one, you use the keyword **this** instead of the class name. AND the call to another constructor (or super constructor) must be the first statement, thus a switch as you coded it won't work.

3.
You probably want to use a static initializer to create a map of Bids, e.g. (untested):

```
private static Map<Integer, Bid> bids = new HashMap<Integer, Bid>();

{
    bids.put(0, new Bid(6, Suit.SPADES));
    // ...
}
```

and then access the map:

```
public Bid getBidByIndex(int pIndex) {
    return bids.get(pIndex);
}
```